# call in script a modal script with post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html+php page with javascript.
In script I have a table with child row. In child row i vold like to open a modal window, that contain a text from mysql database. BUT the modal do not open, if I put into the child row table. From html link  works perfectly.

What can I modify to work.

```
function format ( d ) {
// `d` is the original data object for the row
return '<div class="slider">'+
    '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<th>Operatőr 2:</th>'+
            '<td>'+d.doctor2+'</td>'+
            '<td style="width:100px"></td>'+
            '<th>Leírás: </th>'+
            '<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="getContent.php?id='+d.patientid+'" class="openPopup">'+d.description+'</a></td>'+
            '<td style="width:100px"></td>'+
            '<th>TAJ:</th>'+
            '<td> '+d.patientid+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>'+
'</div>';

$(document).ready(function() {

var table = $('#videos').DataTable( {
    "ajax": 'data.php',
    "columns": [
        {
            "class":          'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "patient" },
        { "data": "patientid" },
        { "data": "diagnose" },
        { "data": "surgerydate" },
        { "data": "description" },
        { "data": "doctor1" },
        { "data": "uploader", "visible": false }

    ]
    }
});


// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#videos tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        $('div.slider', row.child()).slideUp( function () {
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } );
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()), 'no-padding' ).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');

        $('div.slider', row.child()).slideDown();
    }
});

//Modal description
$('.openPopup').on('click',function(){
    var dataURL = $(this).attr('data-href');
    $('.modal-body').load(dataURL,function(){
        $('#myModal').modal({show:true});
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Since this code is incomplete we can only visually inspect it, and not actually run it. If I could, I would use the browsers developer tools to debug this. You can do that! So, does the on click event fire, and retrieve the `dataURL`?

Comment: I have problem only one line:

`'<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="getContent.php?id='+d.patientid+'" class="openPopup">'+d.description+'</a></td>'+`

d.patinetid and d.description are NOT problems

maybe the problem is `href="javascript:void(0);"` , but I do not know other solution

Comment: You could try `href="#"`, but somehow I don't think that will solve the problem.

Comment: I tried, but it did not work

Comment: We try to avoid words like "it did not work" here on SO. They are too vague. "it" probably works fine, but "it" is not related to your problem, as I tried to point out. So, how about the developer tools? Have you looked at the log in the console, done any debugging with breakpoints and watches? This is what you have to do to solve your real problem. To get started press <F12> when using a modern browser on a PC or see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools